# How to pass record from gridview control to pdf viewer Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am trying to create Devexpress Winform Outlook inspired app 2019 Demo Products page. The product page on the Devexpress winform Demo contains gridview controls with rows of images and other texts. When l click on any row it shows pdf that appears on the pdf viewer. I want to know how to create this pdf that contains data from the database. thanks in advance for any assistance provided

Comment: Are you certain that it is displaying a PDF when a user clicks on a grid row? It may simply be showing an edit form databound to the same source as the grid control, or it may be constructing an XtraReport from that data source. I'm not aware of any DevExpress demo that creates a Pdf at runtime from a data source.

Comment: @Brendon it's actually pdf viewer. Pdf viewer only show pdf. When you click on Products on the Navigation bar it will see it